# Can Selenium be used to test something created in Lively Kernel? Is there any tool that would work to test Lively Kernel?

Tags: testing, selenium, kernel, selenium-ide

I tried recording with Selenium IDE while clicking around in Lively Kernel, but I don't think Selenium picks up what I am clicking on correctly. Is this because of how Lively Kernel is made?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think yes, Selenium is capable of working with Lively Kernel. I don't know how much Selenium-IDE is advanced, but writing a WebDriver test in Java should be good - Lively builds up those pages rather nicely! I just tried a very simple one and it got through.

Answer (score 0):

Lively Kernel in its current version mostly uses plain HTML for rendering, so yes there should be no problem.

Comment: When I record using Selenium IDE, the objects I click on come up in the Target as: "//x:div[3]/x:div", "//x:div[11]/x:div", etc.

Comment: Yes, this is the DOM representation of the morphs. Each morph has a shape and both the morph and the shape are represented as DOM elements. For normal morphs / shapes this is a div element.

See the [rendering documentation](http://lively-kernel.org/repository/webwerkstatt/documentation/Rendering.xhtml) for more details.

In case you want to directly reference a morph's element using an id you could do something like that: `morph.renderContext().morphNode.setAttribute('id', 'specialMorph');
`.